# Expecting different type to given type

Tags: asynchronous, rust, websocket, future

I am trying to do some async websocket programming. So far my code looks like

```rust
use native_tls::TlsConnector;
use websocket::client::sync::Client;
use websocket::client::ParseError;
use websocket::futures::{Future, Sink, Stream};
use websocket::r#async::client::ClientNew;
use websocket::stream::sync::TcpStream;
use websocket::stream::sync::TlsStream;
use websocket::ClientBuilder;
use websocket::OwnedMessage;
use websocket::WebSocketError;

fn main() {
    let twitch_websocket_url: &str = "lol";
    let tls_connector: native_tls::Result<TlsConnector> = TlsConnector::new();
    if let Err(error) = tls_connector.as_ref() {
        println!("Error: {}", error);
    }

    let client_builder: Result<ClientBuilder, ParseError> =
        ClientBuilder::new(&twitch_websocket_url);
    if let Err(parse_error) = client_builder.as_ref() {
        println!("Error: {}", parse_error);
    }

    // Get future for async connection.
    let future_conn: ClientNew<TlsStream<TcpStream>> = client_builder
        .unwrap()
        .async_connect_secure(Some(tls_connector.unwrap()));
    if let Err(wserror) = future_conn.as_ref() {
        println!("Error: {}", wserror);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:28:53
    |
28  |       let future_conn: ClientNew<TlsStream<TcpStream>> = client_builder.unwrap()
    |  ______________________-------------------------------___^
    | |                      |
    | |                      expected due to this
29  | |         .async_connect_secure(Some(tls_connector.unwrap()));
    | |___________________________________________________________^ expected struct `native_tls::TlsStream`, found struct `websocket::client::r#async::TlsStream`
    |
```

but this is strange because `ClientNew<TlsStream<TcpStream>>` is not a `native_tls::TlsStream` as seen here https://docs.rs/websocket/latest/websocket/client/async/type.ClientNew.html

I thought maybe there was  mix up with names so I tried removing some use statements but to no avail.

Comment: If you're using futures, you probably want to use an `async fn main()` which means you need some kind of async runtime like Tokio. I think you need `.await` here which is only available in that sort of situation.

Comment: Thanks, I will get to that but just for what im doing which is to return ClientNew<TlsStream<TcpStream>> which is a future allocated on the heap using Box<> I believe this is fine. My understanding is that you only need async when awaiting a future.

Comment: Not sure how useful any of this code will be if you never `await` anything. Futures don't do anything until you act on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling [`websocket::ClientBuilder::async_connect_secure`](https://docs.rs/websocket/latest/websocket/client/builder/struct.ClientBuilder.html#method.async_connect_secure) which returns `ClientNew<TlsStream<TcpStream>>`. If you click the actual `TlsStream` in that return type in the doc page, it takes you to [`websocket::client::async::TlsStream`](https://docs.rs/websocket/latest/websocket/client/async/struct.TlsStream.html). If you compare that `TlsStream` to your `use` [`websocket::stream::sync::TlsStream`](https://docs.rs/websocket/latest/websocket/stream/sync/struct.TlsStream.html) you can see they are clearly different types. In other words, your `let future_conn: ClientNew<TlsStream<TcpStream>>` is declared with the wrong `TlsStream`. If you aren't using this other `TlsStream` anywhere then it's just a matter of fixing your use statements to point to the right one.

As for the compiler error message, it may be helpful to know that `websocket::stream::sync::TlsStream` turns out to just be  a re-export (`pub use`) of `native_tls::TlsStream`.